# Show/hide groups of rows without subtotalling in SSRS 2005?

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have a matrix report in SSRS 2005, and the rows have certain sections.  Imagine along the left a series of

```
1    $100
2    $400
3    $150
4    $650
5    $500
6    $400
7    $900
```

And I want some rows to be able to be hidden.  For example, row 7 are totals of row 5 and 6, so I'd want to +/- next to row 7 that will show/hide rows 5 and 6.  (Note that I don't calculate these totals, they were done by an accountant and it is important that I use the values in the database and don't calculate the totals myself.)

Now I have this "parent/child" relationship in the database, and I could add that as a group on the row

```
       4  1    $100
       4  2    $400
       4  3    $150
   -   4  4    $650
       7  5    $500
       7  6    $400
   -   7  7    $900
```

And then I could add the toggle to that first column, BUT I don't want the values to be subtotaled when they are rolled up.  I simply want rows 5/6 to disappear and only show row 7.  Kind of new to SSRS so any suggestions would be great.

So with one group toggled:

```
   +   4  4    $650
       7  5    $500
       7  6    $400
   -   7  7    $900
```

Other gorup toggled:

```
   +   4  4    $650
   +   7  7    $900
```

Etc.

```
       4  1    $100
       4  2    $400
       4  3    $150
   -   4  4    $650
   +   7  7    $900
```

How can I accomplish this such that I am not recalculating the parent rows(rows 4 and 7 in this example)?

If there is a free web control that can accomplish this in ASP.NET I'd be glad to hear about it as well.  I have a sinking feeling that I'm going to have to write some AJAX myself to accomplish this.  I kind of wondered if there was some hack to embed some javascript into the report that could accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively you have two problems:

1. Report subtotals that come from the database, not calculated
2. Dynamically hide and expose detail rows

You can do this with a standard table report, as follows:

1. Report database subtotals

You can do this in plain SQL (D is the Detail table and G is the Group table):

```
SELECT D.ParentId, D.ChildId, 
D.Description as DetailDescription, D.Amount AS DetailAmount, 
G.GroupDescription, G.GroupAmount
FROM MyTable D INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT ChildId AS GroupId, Max(Description) as GroupDescription, MAX(Amount) AS GroupAmount 
    FROM MyTable 
    GROUP BY ChildId 
    WHERE ChildId IN (SELECT DISTINCT ParentId FROM MyTable)) G ON GroupId = D.ParentId
WHERE D.ChildId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ParentId FROM MyTable)
```

So what we are doing is getting all the rows which aren't subtotals (that is, the rows where the ChildId is not a ParentId) and in the nested select we are also putting the subtotal on every detail line. Now, in the Group on the table, we can simply report the GroupTotal field from our dataset rather than an actual subtotal.

1. Dynamically hide and expose rows

Create a group in your table. Here is where you report the GroupTotal just as a field, not as a total (although you could MAX or MIN it if you wanted to).

Right-click the detail group and click Edit. On the Visibility tab, check the Visibility can be toggled by another report item checkbox and select the textbox name of the first textbox of the group above. Set the Initial Visibility to either Visible or Hidden as required.

Off the top of my head and untested but you should get the idea.

**Edit to explain layout better** (Note: SQL above also edited to show descriptions)

I'm working with a table here, not a matrix.

Layout would look like as follows (first column shows what group you are on):

```
Table Header                 Parent Id               Child Id   Description                                                    Amount
Group1 Header   =Fields!ParentId.Value                          =Last(Fields!GroupDescription.Value)   =Max(Fields!GroupAmount.Value)
Details Group   =Fields!ParentId.Value  =Fields!ChildId.Value   =Fields!DetailDescription.Value            =Fields!DetailAmount.Value
```

Group1 is set to Group on ParentId, only the header is displayed (no footer) and the ParentId Textbox on that group is called ParentIdGroup. Details Group has "Visibility can be toggled by another item" checked and "Report item" is set to ParentIdGroup.

I have mocked up this report now and it works as you describe - what looks like subtotals are actually database fields and the description shows on the group row.

Comment: Just on a first read and looking at your query I think the thing you maybe misunderstood is that the totals are always visible(if you see the example above items 4 and 7 are always visible).  But I think I get the idea and will try this and come back upvote/accept if it gets me where I need.  Thanks.

Comment: I might not understand something, but if I add a new group to show the Group Total, the layout is wrong.  It will be in a seperate column from the values of the other line items.  I need it to be like a balance sheet where all the values and the subtotals are in the same column.

Comment: Is there some way to put in the textbox that shows the value, some expression that would change the value based on the visibilitry of another item?  Something like =If(Child is visible) then Fields!Amount ELSE Fields!GroupAmount so hat if they collapse that section it will show the GroupAmount in the same column

Comment: Ok, solved most of this problem, I gave you an upvote for your help, thanks.

Comment: The idea was to put the GroupAmount on the group row in the same column as the Amount from the detail row so that it looks like a subtotal but is really a database field. Anyway, glad you got it sorted.

Comment: So you mean if I right clicked the amount and chose to add Row?  Or right clicked the existing line number group to the left of amount and chose insert group?  Maybe if you showed what you imagined the layout designer would look like, similar to the block in my below answer, then I would understand better.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by setting the expression for the data field value to Last, since in my case the subtotals are always the last row of the series of rows.  Whenever the rows are expanded, then Last displays the value for each row, since each row is it's own group.  And then whenever I collapse using the PatenLineNumber toggle, then the Last shows the value of that parent row, since it appears as the last row in the group.

So my matrix report is something like this:

```
                                            Amount
ParentLineNumber       ChildLineNumber      =Last(Fields!Amount.Value)
```

I am still having a seperate issue, but that is a seperate question.